# Video Cutting iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

In our Project there is one critical thing which we need to implement . It is like an R & D .The Question here is Once the user shoots his video from iPhone and he will send that to the server .If the video has a size of 200 MB it is very complicated to send that to the server as it takes lot of time to upload it . One thing we have is we need to cut the video once he clicked on Send Button in the screen . Like it needs to cut for every 5 MB and needs to send this to the user ???? Can Some one help us how to tackle this ??? If anyone worked on this please give us some suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `FFMPEG library`

This can break video into chunks and then you can send it to the server.

but i think there may be some other way also to upload video to a server using chunks.

Like **Uploading Objects Using Multipart Upload API**.
Have a look at this:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/AFNetworking-FAQ

:)